# form with and without uploading file (php)

Tags: php

Need your help.
The situation is following. I have simple form with some inputs.
user fill form and can upload or not his logo. But in this code when i press submit button without logo a have an error. So, the question is how can i solve this problem and allow users submit this form with and without uploading the file?? MANY THANKS!!

```
<?
    if(isset($_POST['add'])){    
    $title = sf($_POST['title']);
    $company = sf($_POST['company']);
    $city = sf($_POST['city']);

    $path = '../img/logo';
    // Get extension
    $extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['logo']['name'], '.'), 1));

    $blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4", ".html", ".htm");
    foreach ($blacklist as $item)
    if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['logo']['name'])) exit;
    $type = $_FILES['logo']['type'];
    $size = $_FILES['logo']['size'];
    $filename = DFileHelper::getRandomFileName($path, $extension);
    $target = $path . '/' . $filename . '.' . $extension;
    if (($type != "image/jpg") && ($type != "image/jpeg")) exit; 
    if ($size > 10485760) exit;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], $target);

    $jb = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_job (j_title, j_company, j_city, j_logo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $jb->execute(array($title, $compnay, $city, $filename,));

    echo 'OK';
    Header("Refresh: 2, /jobs/cv");
    }

    ?>

 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">              
    <input type="text" name="title" />
    <input type="text" name="compnay" />
    <input type="text" name="city" />
    <input type="file" name="logo" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

Comment: you should put a condition if the form has a logo. e.g. `if(!empty($_FILES))`

Comment: what rows i should put in this conditions? all rows?

Comment: You have to check if `$_FILES['logo']['error']` is equal to `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`. If it is, then no file has been selected to upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put a condition if the form has a logo

```
<?
    if(isset($_POST['add'])){    
    $title = sf($_POST['title']);
    $company = sf($_POST['company']);
    $city = sf($_POST['city']);
    $filename = "";

    if(!empty($_FILES) && !$_FILES['logo']['error']){ // check if there is a "logo"
        $path = '../img/logo';
        // Get extension
        $extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['logo']['name'], '.'), 1));

        $blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4", ".html", ".htm");
        foreach ($blacklist as $item)
        if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['logo']['name'])) exit;
        $type = $_FILES['logo']['type'];
        $size = $_FILES['logo']['size'];
        $filename = DFileHelper::getRandomFileName($path, $extension);
        $target = $path . '/' . $filename . '.' . $extension;
        if (($type != "image/jpg") && ($type != "image/jpeg")) exit; 
        if ($size > 10485760) exit;

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], $target);
    }

    $jb = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_job (j_title, j_company, j_city, j_logo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $jb->execute(array($title, $compnay, $city, $filename,));

    echo 'OK';
    Header("Refresh: 2, /jobs/cv");
    }

?>
```

Comment: MANY THANKS!! sure, just tired for last 26 hours))

Comment: Well, in my case I always had the file in `$_FILES` even if I didn't select a file to upload. So I had to check if there has been an error to determine if a file has been selected.

Comment: @YaStudio no problem. :) glad i helped and that 26 hours don't need to go up higher. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_FILES["example"])){
    echo true; 
}else{
    echo false;
}
```